# Limit rows by their field sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I am building an inventory control system. I have 2 types of documents:

1. Supply - Document that recieve goods
2. Demand - Document that write off goods

Every supply product has its own selfcost.

When creating Demand i need to understand from which Supplies i will take goods and what is the product quantity from every supply.

For example:

1. Supply 1 - 10 products; selfcost of 1 product - 100
2. Supply 2 - 10 products; selfcost of 1 product - 200
3. Supply 3 - 10 products; selfcost of 1 product - 300

Admin creating the Demand for 15 products. Here i need to understand from which supplies i take goods. So demand will take 10 products from Supply 1 and 5 products from Supply 2.

**How i can filter and take only needed quantity of rows from DB and not take all DB?** In example above i need to take supplies, where their products sum is enough for demand (Supply 1, Supply 2) and NOT take excess supplies (Supply 3) to avoid extra load.

So i need something like that:

```
Get supplies AND limit them by sum of supplies.quantity AND don't take extra supplies
```

*I simplified the structure to leave only needed*

Comment: Why not do what most do and have a unique product id? Then if you have 3 locations have another table that holds the inventory for that product id. Then have a 1 to many relationship on from product to locations. Then you can tell at any point doing a count how many products you have at each location.

Comment: It would be good decision, but every supply make its own selfcost for product and i need to know how many products remain in supply and what is the selfcost.

Comment: I don't understand what a seflcost is.  The "selfcost" is your purchase price? MSRP? Retail price?

Comment: I'm also totally guessing that for supply you mean supplier.

Comment: Selfcost is purchase price.
Supply is the name of document that show how many goods company recieved, what was the price and etc

Answer (score 0):

Then I stand by my comment.  You can just put another column(s) of what it cost to purchase item, what the manufacturer thinks the item is worth(MSRP), what the items actual retail price.  You could also get fancy and do multiple rows with different quantities per purchase price (whole sale price you bought item for).  So your table(s) would look something like this:

```
Product
id   unique_item_id(sku)  description 
1       8675309            Very cool item


Location
id       name         address           phone           description
1    Joe's Place     1234 home st      555.555.5555     Joe's store
2    Bob's Place     5678 home st      666.666.6666     Bob's store
3    Jane's Place    9012 home st      777.777.7777     Jane's store


Inventory
id     sku     location    wholesale_price    msrp      retail       quantity 
1    8675309    1           1.00              6.00        5.00        9
2    8675309    2           1.00              6.00        5.00        15
3    8675309    3           1.00              6.00        5.00        12
4    8675309    3           2.00              6.00        5.00        2
```

Put foreign keys on the inventory table for sku pointing to product and location pointing to location id.

Then in your models:

Inventory

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'sku');
}

public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'id');
}
```

Location

```
public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Inventory::class);
    }
```

Product

```
public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Inventory::class);
    }
```

Then in your controller action where you want to get results you can just do a call like this:

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('sku', '8675308')->with('product')->with(location)->first();
```

This will bring back everything from all tables where the item sku is 8675309. From there it's easy beans to do the logic on how many products total and do the math on costs per location.
***Please note I have not tested this code, this is all off the top of my head. This is merely an example of what can be done to get all the info you need for an inventory system.**